# Double slit experiment in water: A simple demonstration of refractive wavelength?

Tags: waves, refraction, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

The speed and wavelength of light both reduce in media with high refractive index.

However, it is perhaps not intuitively clear how frequency and wavelength behave in refractive media.

A very simple demonstration would be the double slit experiment immersed or embedded in the medium. The fringe spacing could then be directly compared alongside an identical apparatus in air.

Unfortunately, I can't find references to such simple experiments.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Rayleigh refractometer, water between lens and optical flat in Newton’s ring set up, thickness of mica sheet using double slit etc, etc, . .

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a reference? With Newton's rings two media not one is implicitly required and the equations are complicated than for double slit.

Comment: More complicated

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct.  Same could be done in various other liquids like sugar water, mineral oil, etc.

A possible complication would be the necessity of measuring the fringe spacing *in* the liquid, but that can be done.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you possibly have any references to practical demonstrations ?

Comment: Why should any one do such an experiment, you can calculate the outcome. But why not do it yourself, instead of double slit use a cd disk and  one of the small laser pointers do it in air and then in water